# Use FileInfo variable in a file path.

Tags: vb.net, file-io

```
Dim diar1 As IO.FileInfo() = ContractDirectory.GetFiles()
        Dim dra As IO.FileInfo
        Dim CC As Integer
        Dim c As Integer
        For Each dra In diar1
            Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\"[Dra]
        Next
```

So diar 1 is collecting all of the file names in a directory, now I want to process each of the files through a loop accessing each of the file in the directory.

So [Dra] will be a text.txt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need dra to be the name of the file + the extension. `dra.Name` will do this:

```
  For Each dra In diar1
        Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\" & dra.Name
  Next
```